# Is there a way to set the default password while making RDS by cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I made the `RDS` with this script by `cdk`.

It makes the user `myname` as admin, however where can I get the  password?

And also, is there any way to set the default password by script?

```
const dbInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'Instance', {
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.mysql({
    version: rds.MysqlEngineVersion.VER_8_0_19,
  }),
  vpc,
  instanceIdentifier:`st-${targetEnv}-rds`,
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
  },
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
  publiclyAccessible: true,
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  databaseName:`stybot${targetEnv}`,
  credentials: rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('myname')
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your sample code, when you use:

```ts
credentials: rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('myname')
```

CDK will automatically create an [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) secret and store it there. You can view the password generated by [retrieving the secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets.html).

If you want to specify your own password, you can use [Credentials.fromPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.Credentials.html#static-fromwbrpasswordusername-password). The documentation recommends not to have the password directly exposed in your CDK code for security reasons. You can also use [Credentials.fromSecret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.Credentials.html#static-fromwbrsecretsecret-username) to read the value from a AWS Secrets Manager secret you have created separately.